Configure check for multiple condition
ALL,
I have 3 different options to check with configure:
--with-X1
--with-X2
--with-X3
If tye user is not supplying any of them I want to output a warning stating that the default value will be used.
Upon reading the documentation I saw that only one variable can be checked in the configure conditionals at any given time.
So how do I do that? Nested if's?
